# Are there filters other than principal filters? If yes, when?

Tags: boolean-algebra, filters

> Consider a Boolean algebra $\mathcal{B}:=(B,\leq,\lor,\land,^c,0,1)$. Let $\mathcal{F}_\mathcal{B}$ denote the set of all filters on $\mathcal{B}$, and let $\mathcal{F'}_\mathcal{B}$ denote the set of all principal filters on $\mathcal{B}$. Is $\mathcal{F}_\mathcal{B}$ = $\mathcal{F'}_\mathcal{B}$?
>
> $F \subseteq B$ is a filter if -
>
> - $F \neq \phi$
> - If $x,y \in F$ then $x\land y\in F$
> - If $x\in F$ and $x\leq y$ then $y\in F$
>
> Moreover, $F(a) = \{x\in B: a\leq x\}$ denotes the principal filter w.r.t $a\in B$, i.e. the smallest filter containing $a$.

When is $\mathcal{F}_\mathcal{B}$ = $\mathcal{F'}_\mathcal{B}$? Does it have something to do with whether or not the $\mathcal{B}$ is complete? I don't know where to start (except I'm trying to look for counterexamples), and I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Have you studied free filters?

Comment: If you take $\mathscr{B}=\langle\wp(\Bbb N),\subseteq,\cup,\cap,^c,\varnothing,\Bbb N\rangle$, the cofinite filter $$\{\Bbb N\setminus F:F\subseteq\Bbb N\text{ and }F\text{ is finite}\}$$ is a free (i.e., not fixed) filter on $\mathscr{B}$.

Comment: @blargoner I haven't studied free filters yet.

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine: Free filters are simply non-principal filters, like the cofinite filter in my previous comment.